# Pygame - No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

This is the error message:

> C:\Users\DELL G5 5590>pip install pygame Collecting pygame   Using
> cached pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'c:\users\dell g5 5590\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import
> sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\DELL G5
> 5590\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qjygq5mc\pygame\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Users\DELL G5 5590\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qjygq5mc\pygame\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\DELL G5
> 5590\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-3vk36105'
> cwd: C:\Users\DELL G5 5590\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qjygq5mc\pygame
> Complete output (17 lines):
>
> WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
> Using WINDOWS configuration...
>
> **Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to
> "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "", line 1, in    File "C:\Users\DELL G5
> 5590\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qjygq5mc\pygame\setup.py", line
> 194, in 
> buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)   File "C:\Users\DELL G5 5590\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qjygq5mc\pygame\buildconfig\config.py",
> line 210, in main
> deps = CFG.main(**kwds)   File "C:\Users\DELL G5 5590\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qjygq5mc\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py",
> line 576, in main
> and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):   File "C:\Users\DELL G5
> 5590\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qjygq5mc\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py",
> line 302, in ask
> reply = raw_input( EOFError: EOF when reading a line
>
> ---
>
> **
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py
> egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

The OS is Windows.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem and found the solution:
Ok, before giving the solution, let me explain the error...

It is because pygame has not yet released an update for python3.9. They are working with "dev"(pre) versions.
--->>> here's the latest version [v2.0.0.dev14](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/commit/1f1a71c2bda3a6b7a049ffc4943484e244087ab5)

Therefore as this is not yet an official release, the `pip install pygame` command will not find a compatible configuration for this.
So you should use `pip install pygame --pre`.

> `--pre`
> Include pre-release and development versions. By default, pip only finds stable versions.

Then, take a look at [pip Guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#install-pre).

Comment: thanks. but it works fine with after 3.9 to 3.11 ? @daniela Lima